# Searching for GIS data sources relating to the Soviet GULAG system

Tags: data, russia

I'm desperately searching for GIS data related to the Soviet prison camp system, the GULAG. There are quite a few very good maps out there, but I cannot seem to find data in order to make my own. Thinking of locations of the camps, administrative divisions of the penal system etc. Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: You may want to consider posting Questions such as this at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange. Once that site leaves Beta I will probably start to vote for Questions like this to be migrated from here: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3569/are-questions-about-obtaining-geospatial-data-on-topic

Answer (score 2):

Found the data, finally. [Here](https://github.com/urbica/gulag/tree/gh-pages/data).
Found it by pure chance, after searching for years, literally.
Don't know much about the source of the data, except it's from a Moscow design bureau's git. They might have gotten it from the Russian NGO Memorial, they have a lot of data but I was never able to find it georeferenced.